# Unable to find a specification for `GoogleAPIClient/Calendar (~> 1.0.2)`

Tags: ios, google-api, google-calendar-api

I was going through the steps mentioned at [iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) . I am getting following error during pod install

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleAPIClient/Calendar (~> 1.0.2)`

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to stack please supply a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve we cant help you debug your code without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run
*pod repo update*

Also I updated Cocoapods, not sure if this helped
*sudo gem install cocoapods*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar and resolved it with:

1. pod cache clean --all
2. pod deintegrate
3. pod repo update